# How can cuendillar become stronger if it is already indestructible?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

The strength of something is typically measured in what it takes to break it. How can an indestructible thing become stronger?

Comment: It is considered "almost" unbreakable. Not indestructible.

Comment: I have a comment from Mat and an answer from Rand. Perrin want to chime in?

Comment: I tend to consider myself the Perrin, but don't want to change my username.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the problem is simply **insufficiently pedantic language**, but by using even *more* pedantry we can interpret this so that it makes sense.

> "*Cuendillar*," Moiraine said. "Heartstone. No one has been able to make it since the Age of Legends, and even then it was made only for the greatest purpose. Once made, nothing can break it. Not the One Power itself wielded by the greatest Aes Sedai who ever lived aided by the most powerful *sa'angreal* ever made. Any power directed against heartstone only makes it stronger."
>
> <sub>-- *The Eye of the World*, Chapter 52</sub>

Well, evidently *cuendillar* **is** destructible, as they knew even then, having just found the first of the seven seals on the Dark One's prison broken into pieces. So *something* at least is powerful enough to break it, even if only the touch of the Dark One himself.

Bearing this in mind, Moiraine's claim that "nothing can break it" must be taken as a relative statement rather than an absolute one. Nothing *that has ever been devised by mankind* can break it: not conventional weapons, not the One Power. Perhaps only the Creator and the Dark One themselves can break it, but it is possible to be broken.

The statement that "any power directed against heartstone only makes it stronger" makes more sense when we know that it is only *almost* indestructible and not absolutely indestructible: the more people attempt to break it, the more impossible it becomes to actually do so. Alternatively, we could interpret this figuratively: the more power is directed against *cuendillar* while still failing to break it, the more impressive it seems, and as its reputation for indestructibility grows, it becomes 'stronger' at least in human perception.

Comment: Reads to me like nothing *external* can break it, but as we see with the seals, it can eventually deteriorate.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like foolish hyperbolic language to say that any attempt to destroy it only makes it stronger.  But this may contain a seed of its nature;  It may be that Cuendillar is some form of pure order, and that any energy directed at it only increases its order.

We see balefire leaving Cuendillar completely untouched on several occasions. But in at least one case, Cuendillar is destroyed by a direct application of

> The True Power

So it might be more appropriate to say that nothing *in creation* can harm it.